# creating symfony image fixture for SonataMediaBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create an image fixture for SonataMediaBundle. The media is saved in the database and shown in the admin interface, but the image is missing. There is no difference between the records created by fixture and admin interface.

Here is my Fixture in `AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadMediaBundleMediaData`

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Context;
use Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category;

class LoadMediaBundleMediaData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $context = new Context();
        $context->setId('default');
        $context->setName('default');
        $context->setEnabled(true);
        $manager->persist($context);
        $manager->flush();

        $category = new Category();
        $category->setName('Default');
        $category->setContext($context);
        $category->setEnabled(true);
        $manager->persist($category);
        $manager->flush();


        $media1File = new File(__DIR__ . '/../Assets/Images/image.jpg');
        $mediaManager = $this->container->get('sonata.media.manager.media');

        $media1 = $mediaManager->create();
        $media1->setEnabled(true);
        $media1->setBinaryContent($media1File);
        $media1->setName('brunnkogel.jpg');
        $media1->setContext('default');
        $media1->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
        $media1->setProviderStatus(1);

        $mediaManager->save($media1);

        $manager->persist($media1);
        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 40;
    }
}
```

If I create a media in the admin interface it works and the image is saved at `web/uploads/media/default/0001/01/c4412442f8f146db6acaec10751fb54e4c80e8c5.jpeg`. Also the thumbnails are in this directory. If I create the media by fixtures, the files in `web/uploads/media` are missing.

I'm using Symfony 2.8 and SonataMediaBundle 3.0.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to save the media files in the ```web/uploads/media``` folder and give the path (of each file) to the loader?